# Generic event handling

Tags: c#, .net

I am using some .NET framework that allows registering event handlers of a `Action<IMessage>` type.

IMessage is an interface that ALL messages received are implementing.

I would like to be able to (somehow) register handlers that are aware of the concrete type of message received, in order to log it more thoroughly.

Something similar to this:

```
manager.Register(SpecialHandler);

public void SpecialHandler(SpecialMessage msg)
{
   // log.
}
```

- SpecialMessage is a type that implements IMessage.

This is not possible, is there an easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// improved version of Travis Gockel's approach
void Register<T>(Action<T> action, bool invokeOnTypeMismatch = false)
    where T : IMessage
{
    Action<IMessage> wrapped = (msg) =>
        {
            if (msg is T)
            {
                action((T)msg);
            }
            else if (invokeOnTypeMismatch)
            {
                action(default(T));
            }
        };

    // private Action<IMessage> method = delegate{};
    method += wrapped;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class MessageSystem
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<IMessage>> handlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<IMessage>>();

    public void Register<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IMessage
    {
        Action<IMessage> wrapped = (IMessage msg) => action((T)msg);
        handlers[typeof(T)] = wrapped;
    }

    public void Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        handlers[msg.GetType()](msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Travis Gockel: what is `method` here?

Comment: This won't work if msg can't be cast to T (i.e. if two different specialized handlers are registered)

Comment: @Tigran: Good question.  I decided a `Dictionary<Type, Action<IMessage>>` made more sense here.  Also, somebody should think about error cases.

Comment: @TravisGockel regarding error cases: May I guide your eye to my answer? That should pretty much do the trick.

Comment: @Tobias: That is one possible way. But maybe an exception is the right way to deal with error conditions here (you received a message you didn't expect). It really depends on the application. The other error condition (in my code) is if you try to register twice with the same `T`. My register just overwrites, but maybe that isn't good, either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use polymorphism here

Metacode:

```
interface IMessage 
{
    void Handle()
    ... 
}

class MessageFoo : IMessage
{
    void Handle()
    {
        //foo handle
    }
}

class MessageBar : IMessage
{
    void Handle()
    {
        //bar handle
    }
}
```

And this is where you handle them

```
class HandlingManager
{
    void HandleMessage(IMessage m)
    {
        m.Handle(); //knows which concrete type
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but the problem is that now your messages have the behavior tied to their type. So it is impossible to handle the same message in two different ways (depending on who is handling them).

Comment: I do not own the code for IMessage therefore i cannot modify it in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CSharpMessenger Extended](https://www.auto.tuwien.ac.at/wordpress/?p=322)

> This is a delegate-based event system for C#. It uses generics to achieve static typing. As with other messaging systems, such as CSharpEventManager it allows for messaging between event producers and event consumers, without the need for producers or consumers to be aware of each other. The messengers are implemented as static classes, so there is never any need to instantiate a Messenger object. The use of generics means that parameters can be of any type and are not restricted to subclasses of a special Message class - if a callback only needs a float then supply it with a float.